# Getting PDF reader Control in VS.net

Tags: .net, acrobat

is there any way to get the adobe reader control in our visual studio.net without installing the adobe reader in  our system!

Answer (score 1):

WinForm:
[PDF Viewer Control Without Acrobat Reader Installed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/PDFViewerControl.aspx)

Web:
[ASP.NET PDF Viewer User Control Without Acrobat Reader Installed on Client or Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/aspnetpdfviewer.aspx)

The WinForm version doesn't require Reader, but does require the distribution of other freely available DLLs.

I've never tried the Web version.