# A simple PDF viewer windows form

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to display a pdf file in some viewer control by just defining its path without any need for Adobe Acrobat Reader installation.

Is there any open source controls for this ? (with c#)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting PDF reader Control in VS.net ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845309/getting-pdf-reader-control-in-vs-net)

Comment: yes exactly but both 2 links in codeproject are coded in visual basic, I need it with c#

Comment: VB.Net is pretty similar to C#.You should be able to at least get a pretty good idea how to do it and then code it in C# yourself.

Comment: that solution contains 7 different dlls and I'm looking for a toolkit or maybe some controls which is much easier to integrate into my application. I just need to view one pdf in a windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/xpdf_csharp.aspx), which is also on CodeProject?  It's C# and uses/wraps an open source C/C++ PDF library.

The code and compiled binary can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewer-win32/downloads/list) from Google.

I have not used this control, but it seems to meet your requirements.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a brand new PDF viewer control for Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform in C# at http://www.github.com/Swifter/FlipPdfViewer

Answer (score 0):

QuickPDF (www.quickpdf.com) has DARenderPageToDC() and RenderPageToFile() functions that could do the job for you.  It is a reasonably price commercial library and is royalty free.

It is very simple to use in C#.

Also, [Need PDF viewer control - tried a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201692/need-pdf-viewer-control-tried-a-lot)  has a list of PDF viewers that could also do the job.  A commercial library is going to be able to process more complex PDF's if required such as CJK fonts, newer PDF versions, TYPE 1 fonts etc...